# TOTP implementation with Pyotp

Tags: python, totp

I am using the Pyotp module in order to generate the TOTP code for multi-factor authentication.
Is there any way to understand if the URL which I generate the QR code with is scanned by the user or not?

Comment: What does that have to do with Pyotp? As far as I understand, you're asking if a QR scan can be detected

Comment: You can not check for the actual scan. But within the flow the user has to enter a valid code to finish the registration. This will only be possible after the shared secret is transferred (or with enormous luck).

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for your reply.
Actually, I have done everything. I just want to know is there any way to implement this option? like the WhatsApp web app. As you know when you scan the TOTP code you would log in to your account automatically

Comment: @Bharel, yes exactly. like the WhatsApp web app. As you know when you scan the TOTP code you would log in to your account automatically.

Comment: That's the whatsapp app automatically entering the URL and a different backend notifying the web frontend that it entered.

Comment: Please read the first sentence of my earlier comment again!